# C++ Object instantiation memory location

Tags: c++, pointers, object

I ran into a problem today with regards to memory locations of newly allocated objects. I had a loop like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
            GraphNode new_node;
            nodes[x] = &new_node;
}
```

I found that each element of the node[] array received the same address pointer, but I thought that I was instantiating a new instance in each iteration and thus the n objects would have different addresses. I was able to fix the problem with the following code, which resulted in n objects with different addresses, populating my array nodes[]:

```cpp
for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
            GraphNode* new_node = new GraphNode();
            nodes[x] = new_node;
        }
```

What's the difference with these instantiation techniques? Also, it seems weird to me that the first snippet would have such behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, the GraphNode that you create (then print the address of) falls out of scope at the end of the for loop and is reaped. When you create the next one - at the top of the loop - the memory that was used for the last one is again available, and is therefore used for the next GraphNode in the sequence.

In the second example, by calling new, you are explicitly asking the system to reserve storage for that object. Because you allocated it yourself, the GraphNode will never, ever be released, until you do so yourself with a delete. Since they've not been released, their address space isn't free when the next GraphNode is allocated at the top of the loop, and each one gets it's own memory space.

Something to do to see this in action: print something out in the constructor and destructor of GraphNode.

Comment: I would also mention that `GraphNode new_node;` is allocated on the *stack*, and `GraphNode* new_node = new GraphNode();` is allocated on the *heap*. This is the root cause for the different behavior.

Comment: @SHG Afraid not. That would actually make the answer wrong. C++ has no requirement for a stack or heap. The implementor can use whatever they want so long as the requirements for Automatic and Dynamic storage are met.

Comment: Gotta agree with @user4581301. WHERE the memory is allocated is correlated to the lifetime of the allocation, but it's not causal. Generally, yes, the lifetime of a heap allocation is determined by the use of new/delete and the lifetime of a stack object is determined by the lifetime of the stack frame, but the issues are not causal. You could allocate an object in stack memory (FSM help you) or delegate responsibility for a heap object to a smart pointer on the stack. The VAST majority of the time, you can infer lifetime from allocation location, but not always.